# Animate listview items when they are added/removed from datasource

Tags: react-native

Can someone give me an idea of how this can be done, e.g. animate the height from 0 when added and back to 0 when removed?

Comment: Since my listitem is a component I can also rephrase the question to: How do I animate a component just before it unmounts?

Comment: This is a great question and imo it's not replied yet. Is there a way to animate a component on **Unmount**?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Animation when added is easy, just use `Animated` in `componentDidMount` with your listRow , for example:

```
componentDidMount = ()=> {
    Animated.timing(this.state._rowOpacity, {
        toValue: 1,
        duration: 250,
    }).start()
}
```

Animate a component before unmount is much harder in react-native. You should set a handler for `ListView`. When dataSource changed, diff the data, start Animated to hide removed row, and set new dataSource for `ListView`.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation. I'm not sure how to do the handler and diff - do you have some sample code to get me started?

Answer (score 6):

Here you can get full working example for opacity animation:

```
import React from 'react-native';

export default class Cell extends React.Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);

        this.state = {
            opacity: new React.Animated.Value(0)
        };
    }

    componentDidMount() {
        React.Animated.timing(this.state.opacity, {
            toValue: 1,
            duration: 250,
        }).start();
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <React.Animated.View style={[styles.wrapper, {opacity: this.state.opacity}]}>
                <React.Image source={{uri: 'http://placehold.it/150x150'}} style={styles.image}/>
                <React.Text style={styles.text}>
                    Text
                </React.Text>
            </React.Animated.View>
        );
    }
}

const styles = React.StyleSheet.create({
    wrapper: {
        flex: 1,
        flexDirection: 'row',
        justifyContent: 'flex-start',
        alignItems: 'center',
    },
    image: {
        height: 40,
        width: 40,
        marginRight: 16,
        backgroundColor: '#C9D5E6'
    },
    text: {
        fontSize: 20
    }
});
```

Answer (score 2):

In case you need for removing an item from the list, here's how to do the ListRow component:

```js
class DynamicListRow extends Component {
   // these values will need to be fixed either within the component or sent through props
   _defaultHeightValue = 60;
   _defaultTransition  = 500;
   state = {
       _rowHeight  : new Animated.Value(this._defaultHeightValue),
       _rowOpacity : new Animated.Value(0)
   };
   componentDidMount() {
       Animated.timing(this.state._rowOpacity, {
           toValue  : 1,
           duration : this._defaultTransition
       }).start()
   }
   componentWillReceiveProps(nextProps) {
       if (nextProps.remove) {
           this.onRemoving(nextProps.onRemoving);
       } else {
// we need this for iOS because iOS does not reset list row style properties
           this.resetHeight()
       }
   }
   onRemoving(callback) {
       Animated.timing(this.state._rowHeight, {
           toValue  : 0,
           duration : this._defaultTransition
       }).start(callback);
   }
   resetHeight() {
       Animated.timing(this.state._rowHeight, {
           toValue  : this._defaultHeightValue,
           duration : 0
       }).start();
   }
   render() {
       return (
           <Animated.View
               style={{height: this.state._rowHeight, opacity: this.state._rowOpacity}}>
               {this.props.children}
           </Animated.View>
       );
   }
}
```

i've posted a complete tutorial to this question in this blog post. And it's explaining step by step what you need to do to accomplish both adding and removing an item and animate this process.
For adding is pretty straight forward, but for removing looks like it's a little bit more complex.
http://moduscreate.com/react-native-dynamic-animated-lists/

Answer (score 0):

Here's a full example for height and opacity animation. It supports both adding and removing an element. The key point is that you need to reset the height and opacity after the disappearing animation completes. Then you immediately delete the item from the source.

```js
export const ListItem = (props: ListItemProps) => {
  // Start the opacity at 0
  const [fadeAnim] = useState(new Animated.Value(0));

  // Start the height at 0
  const [heightAnim] = useState(new Animated.Value(0));

  /**
   * Helper function for animating the item
   * @param appear - whether the animation should cause the item to appear or disappear
   * @param delay - how long the animation should last (ms)
   * @param callback - callback to be called when the animation finishes
   */
  const _animateItem = (appear: boolean = true, delay: number = 300, callback: () => void = () => null) => {
    Animated.parallel([
      Animated.timing(
        fadeAnim,
        {
          toValue: appear ? 1 : 0,
          duration: delay,
        }
      ),
      Animated.timing(
        heightAnim,
        {
          toValue: appear ? 100 : 0,
          duration: delay,
        }
      ),
    ]).start(callback);
  };

  // Animate the appearance of the item appearing the first time it loads
  // Empty array in useEffect results in this only occuring on the first render
  React.useEffect(() => {
    _animateItem();
  }, []);

  // Reset an item to its original height and opacity
  // Takes a callback to be called once the reset finishes
  // The reset will take 0 seconds and then immediately call the callback.
  const _reset = (callback: () => void) => {
    _animateItem(true,0, callback);
  }

  // Deletes an item from the list. Follows the following order:
  // 1) Animate the item disappearing. On completion:
  // 2) Reset the item to its original display height (in 0 seconds). On completion:
  // 3) Call the parent to let it know to remove the item from the list
  const _delete = () => {
    _animateItem(false, 200, () => _reset(props.delete));
  };

  return (
      <Animated.View
        style={{height: heightAnim, opacity: fadeAnim, flexDirection: 'row'}}>
        <Text>{props.text}</Text>
        <Button onPress={() => _delete()}><Text>Delete</Text></Button>
      </Animated.View>
  );
}
```