# Delete item from ListView with animation

Tags: react-native

I have a ListView with a custom component (it is a swipeable component so sliding on it shows delete button). I want to delete the item from the list view on pressing the delete button with a sliding animation.

This is my code for the Delete Button onPress function:

```
deleteItemAndPassId = (id) => {
    Animated.timing(this.state.x, {
      toValue: -1000,
      duration: 2000,
    }).start();
    this.props.deleteItemWithId(id); // calls parent's delete item which deletes it from the data array
  }
```

The problem is the item gets deleted fast (before the animation completes) and the listview data source updates, after then the animation completes hence giving me an empty row. The layout returns to normal on restarting the app though (therefore there is no error in the deletion of the item).

So can anyone tell me how to synchronize the animation and the deletion.
Thanks in advance!

Comment: Did you find any solution to animate delete event ?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Animate listview items when they are added/removed from datasource](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31997126/animate-listview-items-when-they-are-added-removed-from-datasource)

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to move the deletion code to the animations's [completion callback](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/animated.html#working-with-animations), which is the first optional argument to `.start()`:

```
Animated.timing(this.state.x, {
  toValue: -1000,
  duration: 2000,
}).start(() => {
  this.props.deleteItemWithId(id);
});
```

Comment: Doesn't work. What happens is that after the particular item slides away,  the state updates the exact same moment. So the screen refreshes and the item below moves up at the same time to take the removed item position thus leaving a gray box in between the list.

Comment: I think I have figured out the problem. The list item slides out of the view on deleting but on re-render I have set no code to place it back to its original position. Therefore there is a gray empty space there!. Can you show me an easy way to somehow reset the this.state.x position after animating once?

Comment: This doesn't solve the issue. The item below will slide up to take the previous item's place and will have the new opacity/position applied to it. This will make it look like two items disappeared.